# Linkedin APIs for authentication, connection invitations and user search

Tags: react-native, mobile, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I wrote this same question to #Linkedin support service and I was redirected to [this](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170?lang=en) link where they indicate to ask questions in Stackoverflow.

We are developing a mobile App for the Polytechnic University of Madrid and we plan to expand to other Universities in the future. This aplication will need in a first instance OAuth via Linkedin. It will also need to allow the authenticated user to send connection invitations to other users contained in a list. For creating that list of users, it will be useful if the admin of the system could search in a bar similar to the one which Linkedin has, write a user name and select it, retrieving its user ID or what is needed to identify the invitation destination.

Summing up, the App needs:

- OAuth API
- Connection request API
- User search API

I have read on the web that some of Linkedin's APIs suffered some modifications in which most of them where limited to allowed users or apps. So the aim of this post is knowing:

1. Do the APIs my mobile application needs exist?
2. What do I need to do to obtain the access to those APIs in case they exist?

Answer (score 0):

> User search API

For this feature you could use something like [Algolia Instant Search](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/?language=react#getting-started-with-react-native-instantsearch)

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn has changed many things related to user data. If you need access to its data then you must follow the given guidelines.

Basically you have to create a LinkedIn App and then the users have to grant permissions to your app by installing it in their device(s) and then only you can collect their data.